# Should I make bigger fewer game engines or many smaller game engines?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have recently hit 1M dollars and got into a new office yet the only engine I have is still my first engine.
I have researched a good amount amount of engine features, but I am trying to research every currently available feature before making an engine so I can use this single engine for every genre.
But is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have attempted both and had success with both. What I can say is that in the initial phase you just need one good one, right when the gameling comes on the market. After that you can make sequels to games with older game engines. Doesn't matter how long ago the original was made, just that your current engine is better (not a bit, not a whole lot, just enough ... I'd say at least 2 new things for every stage of development)